# Why does starting a process in VS Debugger take a much longer time on the first run?

Tags: c#, .net, process

I am evaluating the performance of a program written in C# that calls an external python program. I'm using the stopwatch to compare the performance

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
//code...
watch.Stop();
var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

The external Python program is called using:

```
Process.Start(start)
```

The first time I execute it under a debugger I get around 17-26 elapsed seconds. The next time I execute it, I get 700 ms. If I restart the computer, and rerun the test, I would get a time elapsed in the range of 17-26 seconds.  Am I correct in assuming that after the first Debug, Visual studio keeps the process in the memory and that way speeds up the execution, even though I stopped the Debugging. I've checked the task manager if "python" was running, but didn't see an entry for it between runs.

Comment: That is not correct. The sub-process is independent of VS and is not kept in memory. There are, however, other bits of the system outside of VS.. what is the behavior when running the same program in say, a shell?

Comment: Are you resetting the Stopwatch? If not, it will continue where it left off last time.

Comment: @JonVote First run is 17-26 seconds, second run is 700ms.

Comment: *Visual studio keeps the process in the memory* Not VS but system can ... also python may recompile your script first time

Comment: @user2864740 I tried running it outside the .NET environment and just using the command line with a python profiler:

    python -m cProfile file.py arguments

And observed the same behaviour. So .NET doesn't have anything to do with it. The first time I run the python program it takes a very long time >20 seconds. The next execution is much faster. The python program reads a list of variables from a file and then fits it to a plynomial curve using the scipy library.